# "Алл", "Инн" при обращении — допустимо ли?

Tags: грамотная-речь, окончания, обращение

Допустимо ли при обращении использовать такие формы, как "Алл", "Инн", образованные от имён Алла и Инна, и им подобные? Если нет, то только ли из-за того, что странно смотрятся на письме две одинаковые согласные на конце без гласной в таких случаях? А в разговорной речи это допустимо?

Если недопустимы на письме такие формы, то обращения Славк, Ваньк так же недопустимы или даже ещё сильнее невозможны?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для имен ***Алла, Инна*** сокращенные формы могут выглядеть как ***Ал, Ин*** (усечение двойной согласной, сравнить Алка, Инка), но и такая графика смотрится не лучшим образом.

Обращения ***Ваньк, Сашк*** фонетически неудобны, поэтому они применяются реже, чем ***Вань, Саш***.

Соответственно,  определенные ограничения есть, но в целом  формы этого  "новозвательного" падежа в современном языке допускаются.

**Материал из статьи** http://psyjournals.ru/files/74124/langpsy_2014_n4_Vitali.pdf

Первые примеры **усечённого вокатива** обнаруживаются довольно рано, они существовали ещё до 1917 г. **Микит!** Не докличешься.  **Акуль**, поди загони. [Л. Н. Толстой. Власть тьми  (1887)]; **Володь,** брось-ка ты эти штуковины, - сказал я ему как-то. [С. Н. Сергеев-Ценский. Благая весть (1912)]

В ранний советский период – 20-е и 30-е годы – расширялся круг авторов у которых  встречается эта форма. Усечённые обращения часты у А. Н. Толстого и Горького и особенно характерны для языка Платонова. **«Анютк,** поди сюда, дело есть!» - крикнула она звонко. [И. А. Бунин. Митина любовь (1924)];

В 60-е годы ХХ века усечение начало проникать в язык «интеллигентной прозы»,  Сегодня **усечённые формы кажутся уже совершенно нейтральными.**

Comment: Спасибо! А есть какие-то источники, подтверждающие усечение двойной согласной в новозвательном?

Comment: Нет источников, просто в Сети обсуждаются варианты сокращения. Но звательный падеж - это  ненормированная форма, поэтому и правил нет. Я думаю, что в устной речи проблем с этими именами нет, а в письменной звательный падеж лучше не использовать: оба варианта выглядят странно.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. *...а в письменной звательный падеж лучше не использовать...* Вы говорите это только об Алле и Инне и подобных, правильно я понял? Например "Ань", "Марин" нормально ведь будет и на письме, Вы согласны? (Забыл сразу принять ответ, кстати.)

Comment: В качестве записи разговорного варианта эти формы допускаются, так как они  фактически используются в речи.

Comment: А как можно обращаться к Риммам? :)

Comment: Можно, наверное, в личной  дружеской переписке использовать форму "Рим", адресат вас поймет, если ее действительно зовут "Римма", и вряд ли обидится. Главное, по тексту должно быть ясно, что это именно звательный падеж имени, а не город.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon! Значит, только в дружеской.))

Comment: Ну да, а то вдруг у человека плохо с юмором.