# Допустимость современного звательного падежа в именах

Tags: грамотная-речь, этикет

Вопрос возник, когда вспомнил комментарий Sharon к [этому](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448369/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%BB-%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BD-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8) своему вопросу:

> Можно, наверное, в ***личной дружеской переписке*** использовать форму "Рим", адресат вас поймёт, если её действительно зовут "Римма", и вряд ли обидится. Главное, по тексту должно быть ясно, что это именно звательный падеж имени, а не город.

И ещё немного процитирую её же ответ:

> Для имен **Алла, Инна** сокращённые формы могут выглядеть как **Ал, Ин** (усечение двойной согласной, сравнить Алка, Инка), но и такая графика смотрится не лучшим образом.

Проблема только в этих именах, в которых усечение согласной смотрится не лучшим образом или можно перепутать с городом, или всё-таки в любом случае обращения *Миш, Марин, Тань, Насть, Коль* подходят только для дружеской переписки или хотя бы когда видно, что знакомство получилось очень приятным и располагает к менее формальным отношениям?

Answer (score 1):

**Это стилистическая принадлежность разговорной речи**. Хочется сказать, что даже статус данной формы слова пока остаётся предметом споров учёных: часть склоняется к выделению подобной формы в отдельную грамматическую категорию, часть же выступает против. https://poisk-ru.ru/s23780t16.html

Если вдуматься, мы используем **не звательный падеж** существительных (морфологическая категория), а **обращение** (категория синтаксиса). Это разные вещи. В древнерусском языке был звательный падеж, но мы сейчас в качестве обращения используем именительный, находя остатки звательного лишь в устойчивых выражениях (Господи, Боже мой) и в некоторых художественных произведениях, например, в пушкинской "Сказке о рыбаке и рыбке" (Чего тебе надобно, старче). Пушкин употребляет эту форму, чтобы показать неопределённое художественное время — старину, а в XIX веке звательного падежа в русском языке уже не было. То, что обращения произносятся в русском языке со звательной интонацией, вовсе не говорит о наличии в нём звательного падежа. Звательная интонация — это не морфологический признак, каковым, к примеру, является определённое окончание, а всего лишь интонирование.

Есть научная работа на эту тему. Супрун В. И. Особенности использования вокативных единиц в современном русском языке. Электронный научно-образовательный журнал ВГПУ «Грани познания». 5 (10). Декабрь:

> В разговорной речи имена собственные, их сокращённые формы и существительные, обозначающие разные степени родства (мама, папа, дедушка, бабушка, дядя, тётя), в функции обращения нередко принимают особую усечённую форму, без окончания, которую **некоторые** исследователи считают особым звательным падежом. Звательные усечённые формы, появившиеся в русской разговорной речи, **не полностью рассматриваются в рамках падежной парадигмы. Ведь эти формы ограниченные разговорно-обиходной сферой, употребляются с завидной регулярностью и в аналогичных контекстах.** Они образуются от имён существительных мужского и женского рода группы терминов родства и личных имён на -а//-я в именительном падеже при помощи нулевой флексии (пап!, тёть!, Гень! Тань! Варвар! Никит!): «Анютк, поди сюда, дело есть!» - крикнула она звонко.
>
> Регулярность этих форм даёт все основания утверждать наличие в современном русском языке нового звательного падежа. Прагматическую адресатную семантику вобрал в себя также именительный падеж, форма которого является литературной в современном русском языке [13]. Назовём эту форму ново-звательным, как предлагает Забазнов на его сайте «Этот удивительный русский язык», чтобы отличать ее от древнего звательного. Ново-звательный падеж есть у группы уменьшительных: "Ты, Зин, уж лучше помолчала бы!" (В. С. Высоцкий, «Диалог у телевизора»). Ещё ново-звательный падеж есть, редкий случай, у двух слов во множественном числе: "ребята" и "девчата" ("ребят", "девчат"). Время от времени можно даже слышать: "Мужчина! Мужчин!" Этот падеж образуется посредством усечения окончания до нулевого. Но иногда, он может отличаться и специально добавленным окончанием: "Дениса! Пора домой!" или (собаке по кличке Бим) "Бима! Ко мне!" Поскольку при обращении может использоваться и именительный падеж, ново-звательный является не обязательным, а факультативным падежом. В некоторых случаях это обращение может быть адресовано друзьям семьи, хорошим знакомым.  Оно употреблялось **для передачи простонародного языка, а после «оттепели» начали его употреблять для изображения живой и разговорной речи.**
>
> В 60-е годы ХХ века усечение начало проникать в язык «интеллигентной прозы», что означает и расширение его устного узуса и одновременно его письменную кодификацию. Это, скорее всего, говорит о значительном расширении использования усечения в устной речи. Сегодня усечённые формы кажутся уже совершенно нейтральными. В современном языке осталось значение неформальности и прагматика малой социальной дистанции между собеседниками.
>
> **В начале своего существования эти усечения могли восприниматься не как грамматические формы, а как орфографические имитации, воспроизведения фонетических особенностей устных форм обращения**. Далее, в 60-х годах такие вокативы, как пап и Саш, стали **кодифицированным знаком устной речи в письменном тексте.** В современных письменных текстах встречаются и такие примеры, которые воспринимаются как имитация Са-а-а-ша-а. Некоторые обращения, как Татьян Николавн и формы с конечными кластерами (Мишк), кажутся не вполне кодифицированными. Формы обращения, называя того, к кому адресована речь, занимают независимую позицию в церковнославянском и русском предложении, сосредотачиваясь либо в его начале, либо в середине, либо в конце.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила! И всё-таки Вы на вопрос не ответили. Только в этих случаях?

Comment: *часть склоняется к выделению подобной формы в отдельную грамматическую категорию* - эк его. Неужели так сразу в ***категорию***? То есть категориями существительного будут род, число, падеж и "звательный падеж"? Вот за что люблю этих самоделкиных, так это за употреляючи словов, значения не знамши которым.

Comment: Артём, я думала, что понятно ответила: не только эти, а все усечённые формы обращений употребляются только в разговорном стиле - в неформальной обстановке при малой социальной дистанции между собеседниками.